# Can't connect to DB2 with DataGrip with securityMechanism=13

Tags: jdbc, db2, datagrip

I'm trying to make a connection with the DB2 database with DataGrip. For the connection `securityMechanism=13` is needed.

The connection failed with the following message:

> [-4223] [jcc][1071][10615][3.68.61] Caught
> java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException while initializing
> EncryptionManager.  See attached Throwable for details.
> ERRORCODE=-4223, SQLSTATE=null DH key size must be multiple of 64, and
> can only range from 512 to 8192 (inclusive). The specific key size 256
> is not supported.

We used the following string:

```
 jdbc:db2://<ip-adress>:<port>/<schema>:securityMechanism=13;
```

When we disable the security measures we can connect to the database, but as soon as the ENCRYPTED_USER_PASSWORD_AND_DATA_SECURITY is enabled, we can't setup a connection.

We also use DataStudio and with this application it is possible to create a jdbc connection to the DB2 database. We prefer to use DataGrip because we need to maintain different types of databases which is not possible in DataStudio.

Comment: Compare the exact version of the jvm/jdk/jre  being used in the success case (IBM DataStudio), versus the failing case (DataGrip).  You may find that the failing case uses java 11 or higher,  and if that is true, then this technote will give the reason: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/jdbc-data-encrypt

Answer (score 1):

FYI from [Security under the IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_cjvjcsec.html)

> Important: The DATA_ENCRYPT authentication type is deprecated and might be removed in a future release.

> To encrypt data in-transit between clients and Db2® on Linux®, UNIX, and Windows systems databases, we recommend that you use the Db2 on Linux, UNIX, and Windows systems database system support of Secure Sockets Layer (SSL).

and from https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/jdbc-data-encrypt

> Data_encrypt is not supported  db2 v11  onwards.  There is no plan to support DATA_ENCRYPT with openJDK 11. The recommendations is to use SSL.

Answer (score 0):

DataGrip uses JAVA 11 and `DATA_ENCRYPT` doesn't support JAVA 11

Comment: Your first language might not be English. It is incorrect to write "is not working",  because IBM purposefully removed support for this feature. So it is "by design". It is __working they way IBM intended__ .  IBM forces you to configure your Db2-instance and clients to use SSL/TLS instead.